# Populating SQL database table by retrieving data from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL (but have experience in other programming languages) and I'm taking on a side project at work that involves creating a database of our team's financials. Ultimately what I want to do is have this database retrieve data from a specific table in a worksheet and then populate a database table. I'm sure this is possible but how would I go about doing this? I'm currently familiarizing myself with PostgreSQL as I found it to be the most beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Dbeaver where i can export the data of any table in to CSV , once i have data in CSV , i can create .sql file back using online http://codebeautify.org/csv-to-sql-converter which then can be executed on any other same db.

Answer (score 0):

This will help get you a cell range exported to CSV:
[Export sheet from Excel to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686695/export-sheet-from-excel-to-csv)

Then use this to get the CSV into PostgreSQL:
[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)